# Vertical algnment GWT panels

Tags: gwt

I am having problems correctly aligning my content in `DecoratorPanel` in GWT.

Using the following code snippet, all the content appears to be vertically aligned to the middle (?)

```
DecoratorPanel decor = new DecoratorPanel();
decor.setHeight("100%");
decor.add(new Label("Test"));
```

Diagram to explain:

```
             --------                 --------
I get this:  |      |    I want this: |test  |
             |      |                 |      |
             |test  |                 |      |
             |      |                 |      |
             |      |                 |      |
             --------                 --------
```

I have tried `decor.getElement().getStyle().setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.TOP);`, but it does not seem to affect anything.

How do I align the content to the top of the panel?

**Update:**

I have notice that if I use a `LayoutPanel` instead of a `DecorPanel` everything seems to align properly.

Could the problem be that I am using regular `Panels` with `LayoutPanels`? If so, why am i having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DecoratorPanel` uses a HTML `table`, while the other use a `div`. So with the `DecoratorPanel` you set the vertical style on the `table` element instead of the content, which explains what you see and a reason for not to use this panel. So you either should use a `div` based panel or set the alignment on the label or the `td` (which is `label.getElement().getParent()`, but that's a bit ugly and prone to future bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Get the `td` element.

`... . getElement().setStyleName("myStyle");`

Then in your css

```
.myStyle td{
vAlign : centre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DecoratorPanel is 9-box panel which is used to place images around, specially for rounded corner effect of widgets it mostly useful, there is a a cells around you widget when you set 100% it might be applying some width and height of all cells you are seeing the label in center.